# "contract creation code storage out of gas" always getting this error while deploying on eth mainnet

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, erc-721, mainnet

I'm trying to deploy this simple NFT contract https://github.com/NishantPacharne/new-contract/blob/main/contract.sol .. I was able to deploy correctly on goerli testnet https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ae44cb66af5f312839f27c6acfe4c4e9a19ce659745ab97c8110d621b296b40

But when trying to deploy on mainnet it gives me this error "contract creation code storage out of gas" no matter what gas limit I set .. I always get this error on remix.

Comment: Hey have you found a solution to this ?